# How to patch an existing Kubernetes manifest with a new image version?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pretty basic use case:

- I have a repository containing a bunch of deployment yml files. They use both private and public registries.
- I would like to be able to patch those yamls programatically to simply update the image tags when new versions are published in those repositories
- the yamls in my git repo must be "deployable" eg: can't use some placeholders instead of version tags
- I do not want to apply the manifests, I just want to patch them (eg: the way Weave Flux does it, as it can watch Docker registries, then it patches manifests and also applies them).

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `I would like to be able to patch those yamls programatically` ?
Do you want to patch image tags in deployed resources or in manifest files in your repository?
If you want to patch/update image tags in yaml files in your repo based on diffrent registries, I'm afraid it can be difficult to achieve.

Comment: @PjoterS I mean patch files in my git repo based on different registries. It's more of a matter of manipulation as in (at least in some cases) I have the means to get the required tags from remote registries.

Comment: I believe [`kustomize`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize#readme) is the most obvious way, although yaml is a computer parseable file format, so only the preservation of comments would stop you from `yaml.save(fixup(yaml.load(...)))`. While this isn't what you asked, this is the very problem `helm` was designed to solve, also, and is how we inject image changes